# Aligning elements from two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a project and need to display elements from a **string array** and an **integer array** in **two horizontal rows**, as follows...

```
name1 | name 2 | name3 |

 111___ | 2222__   |3333__  |
```

I'm having trouble **aligning the vertical separators**. We are supposed to be learning foundational work so we are not supposed to use objects. Can anyone help?

Comment: Bad news, Java arrays **are** Objects.

Answer (score 0):

When displaying the elements of each array, complete with spaces depending on the width of the cell you want. This width can be created as a third array or in-place, as the maximum between the width of the string and the width of the integer.

```
int[] cellWidth = new int[yourIntegerArray.length];
for (int index = 0; index < cellWidth.length; index++) {
    Integer i = yourIntegerArray[index];
    String s = yourStringArray[index];
    cellWidth[index] = Math.max(s.length(), i.toString().length());    
}
```

Then, when displaying the numbers for instance:

```
for (int index = 0; index < yourIntegerArray.length; index++) {
    Integer i = yourIntegerArray[index];

    // print the number
    System.out.print(i);

    // add the spaces
    int nbSpacesToAdd = cellWidth[index] - i.toString().length;
    printSpaces(nbSpacesToAdd); // you should write that one easily

    // print the separator
    System.out.print("|");
}
```